# Username using * in the criteria countif

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i m searching sum of class of each student using countif formula, but any student have unique username like A*di (in the image) and so the calculation is false. And any other student using username like </John>, and 'Angel. and make calculation false

**Formula:**  `=COUNTIF('Data Asli'!$A:$A,$A$2)`

[image: photograph of computer screen]

Comment: Hi Fatimah - welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please clarify your question and include any relevant code as text and not an image? Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This photo shows the program on your monitor is Google sheets, not Excel.

Comment: Also, why not use a screenshot instead of a photo?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(..))` to run an exact, case-sensitive comparison that ignores wildcards:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT('Data Asli'!$A:$A,$A2))
```

**How it works:**
`EXACT(Value1, Value2)` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, depending on whether the 2 values *exactly* match (same capitals, no wildcards, et cetera)

`--` will convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` into `1`/`0`

`SUMPRODUCT(Array1[,Array2])` will run down the arrays, multiply the numbers together, then add them.  It also forces many functions to both treat a Range as an array, and output an array.

So, as an example, the steps run like this:

> `=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(A1:A5, A2))`

> `=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT({Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value2}, Value2))`
>   a.k.a.
>   `=SUMPRODUCT(--{EXACT(Value1,Value2),EXACT(Value2,Value2),EXACT(Value3,Value2),EXACT(Value4,Value2),EXACT(Value2,Value2)})`

> `=SUMPRODUCT(--{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE})`

> `=SUMPRODUCT({0,1,0,0,1})`

> `=2`